# Deprecation of the enum UITextAlignment in favor of NSTextAlignment in iOS6

Tags: ios, deprecated, ios6

While compiling my app for iOS6 I get the following deprecation message:

From iOS 6 and later UITextAlignmentCenter is deprecated. Use NSTextAlignmentCenter instead.

Easy fix I thought, but it seems that NSTextAlignment is available in iOS 6.0 and later, and I also still want to support iOS 5. What is best practice to solve this problem?

Should I check which iOS the user is running and then use NSTextAlignment or UITextAlignment based on that?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Deprecated means just that - its going away in the future. If it were me, I'd just wait til your app is going to be iOS6 or newer (I assume in the next year you will do that). Its extremely unlikely for Apple to remove it before Xcode stops supporting the older release its needed in.

Comment: Yes, and since the "new" values are the same as the old values, you can use the "NS" values without fear of it failing in older versions.

Comment: But, is the "NS" value defined in the iOS5 SDK? If not @DanMorrow, what do you suggest, adding your own #define wrapped in an ifdef < iOS6 ?

Comment: No, the "NS" value is not defined in the iOS SDK. What I'm saying is that if you look at the values, they resolve to the same value, so it doesn't matter. Unless you have other developers on your team that are using an older version of XCode, then don't worrry about it.  UITextAlignmentCenter has a value of 1. NSTextAlignmentCenter ALSO has a value of 1. This value, while not defined in the iOS 5 SDK, will work when running under iOS 5, because the values resolve to the same thing.